# What is the proper way to `ignore` an IDisposable?

Tags: f#

I need to make a call to a function that returns some value that I don't need. Normally, I'll just pipe that to `ignore`. But what if the returned value is an `IDisposable`?

Does the `ignore` operator take care of disposing the passed argument? From the source code of it, looks like it doesn't:

```
[<CompiledName("Ignore")>]
let inline ignore _ = ()
```

So for this purpose, instead of writing `use __ = someFunc ()`, I use this function:

```
let inline dispose (x : #IDisposable) = x.Dispose()

// usage example
someFunc () |> dispose
```

I wonder, is this the right way to do it or maybe there's already a built-in operator like this? Or will it be fine to just use `ignore`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233240.aspx).

```
using (someFunc ()) ignore
```

Another option is `use`, which is a language construct rather than a function.

```
use x = someFunc()
()
```

Comment: I guess, `use` is preferred - with `using`, `Dispose` will be called at the end of the function or lambda expression; with `use`, `Dispose` would be  called at the end of the code block.

Comment: Great, `using x ignore` look nice, and it will handle exceptions properly. I'll change my `dispose` function to be `let dispose x = using x ignore` instead.

Comment: BTW, `use _ = ...` won't compile as single underscore is not accepted as identifier.

Comment: @MisterMetaphor Hmm, I expected it to accept a pattern rather than an identifier. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
someFunc().Dispose()
```

Comment: Simple and functional! Although probably not as convenient as `ignore` because you can't `|>` to `Dispose()`.

Comment: Coz Dispose is a method and not a function